# What SQL or PL/SQL on Oracle 11g would keep a connection from being idle?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I'm doing some basic database learning on Oracle 11g over a Citrix client. The problem is, if I'm idle about 5 minutes, I get disconnected. What would be the simplest SQL statement or PL/SQL procedure for keeping a sort of ping of activity going every minute to stay connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to dbms_lock you can create an infinite loop that sleeps 60 seconds each time.  If you don't have access to dbms_lock try user_lock.sleep instead, although that function is not installed by default.  (And if you do use it, change the 60 (seconds) to 60000 (milliseconds)).

```
begin
    for i in 1 .. 9999999 loop
        dbms_lock.sleep(60);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `select 1 from dual`

Comment: `select 1 from dual` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310851/what-is-the-use-of-dual-table-in-oracle

Comment: Would that be continuous activity over the connection? I'd rather keep it to a minimum so it doesn't affect other users... Feel free to laugh at me if this would be a minimal performance problem.

Comment: It's just a no-op you can type in whenever you want.  If you want something to run automatically, you'll have to wait for someone more familiar with the particulars of Oracle.

Comment: Yeah, I'd want it to run automatically. So far I'm just typing 'a' in the SQL*Plus prompt and it says "nothing to append" which works for me except that I forget to do it while researching on the web.

Answer (score -1):

Try `dbms.sleep(0.1)` or `dbms.sleep(0.01)`.  Works fine for me.

Comment: "declare a date ; b date ; begin a := sysdate ; for i in   1 .. 1000 loop dbms_lock.sleep(0.01 ); end loop ; b:= sysdate ; DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( (b-a) *24*60*60*1000); END ; "

 Retrieved DBMS_OUTPUT content:

Comment: 11000   (11k millisecs).

With 0.1:

declare a date ; b date ; begin a := sysdate ; for i in   1 .. 100 loop dbms_lock.sleep(0.1 ); end loop ; b:= sysdate ; DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( (b-a) *24*60*60*1000); END ;

Sleep 0.1 seconds 100 times

 Retrieved DBMS_OUTPUT content:
10000